# Получить namespace MainPage или App

Tags: c#, namespace, windowsphone

Как из кода с `namespace` к примеру `First.Second.Third` получить `namespace` приложения?
Нужно из плагина получить пространство имен приложения(они отличаются), для доступа к текущему экземпляру класса. Конечно можно вручную вводить, но у меня скрипт на 50 похожих приложений, у которых отличается `namespace` (в обязательном порядке), так что хотелось бы сделать это программно.
Суть сводится к тому чтобы из этой строки:

```
var mainPage = (((App)Application.Current).RootPage);
```

сделать эту:

```
var mainPage = (((my.namespace.App)Application.Current).RootPage);
```

есть возможность передать в аргумент функции, которая использует эту строку нужный namespace, но (привычка к js) тут не получается в приведение типов вставить переменную, которая подставится в нужное время и сделает все красиво((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы что-то делаете не так. Ну, получили вы строку с namespace'ом приложения, что вы с ней дальше-то делать будете?

Отучайтесь от джаваскриптовских привычек, C# — полностью другой язык.

---

Ответьте для начала на вопрос: почему вы предполагаете, что у `Application` есть поле `RootPage`? [Документация](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Windows.Application%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) такого вроде бы не гарантирует.

---

Не-не, «некогда учить» — не аргумент.

Если Application-классы под вашим контролем, пусть они имплементируют общий интерфейс

```
interface IStxApplication
{
    Window RootWindow { get; }
}
```

Comment: я его сам сделал. Это исключительная ситуация - сделаю и сразу отучусь от js))))
И вообще, мне с# нужен только для этого проекта и очень срочно, потому некогда его учить. А под рукой нет человека в нем разбирающегося. То, что похоже на Java я осилил, но некоторые различия просто ставят меня в тупик Х_Х

Comment: О, спасибо большое)
 Обязательно найду время))